# Sonata SEO- How to translate the text I put in the sonata_seo.yaml file?

Tags: seo, sonata, symfony-sonata

how to translate the meta tags we configure in SonataSeoBundle?
See the file

```yaml
# config/packages/sonata_seo.yaml

sonata_seo:
    encoding: UTF-8
    page:            
        default: sonata.seo.page.default
        metas:
            name:
                keywords: Lorem, ipsum dolor, sit amet, consectetur    
                description: Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod
    tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam
```

[See the screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SoBrU.png)

Comment: Please post the code or error into your question, not an image.

Comment: It has no errors. I am looking for a way to translate the text I put in the tags. I didn't see this in the documentation.

Comment: Are you looking for a text translation service or are you wondering how translated text needs to be inserted into this framework?

Comment: @StephenOstermiller I am not looking for a translation service. I use the translation system of the Symfony framework to manage the translation. Now I wonder how to translate this text because SonataSeoBundle offers a configuration file in which I can put the meta tags to be displayed but it is not mentioned in the documentation the translation management